# Weitzenböck Identities

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

The Wikipedia page for [Weitzenböck identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck_identity) is explicitly example based. I am looking for a reference which takes a more rigorous approach (as well as a discussion of the Bochner technique). In particular, I am interested in references which focus on these identities in complex geometry.

I have already consulted Griffiths & Harris which is mentioned in the article, but it only contains one example. Berger's *A Panoramic View of Riemannian Geometry* doesn't have much more.

---

My interest in Weitzenböck identities has been motivated by a question arising from the following theorem:

> Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold and $E$ a hermitian holomorphic vector bundle with Chern connection $\nabla$. Then for the Laplacians $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \bar{\partial}\bar{\partial}^* + \bar{\partial}^*\bar{\partial}$, $\Delta_{\partial} = \partial\partial^* + \partial^*\partial$, we have $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \Delta_{\partial} + [iF_{\nabla}, \Lambda]$.

Is $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \Delta_{\partial} + [iF_{\nabla}, \Lambda]$ an example of a Weitzenböck identity?

---

As I have not received any comments or answers, I have posted this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107168/weitzenbock-identities). Those interested may be able to find some helpful answers there.

Comment: It is usually recommended that one waits a bit longer than a day, say a week or so, but I think in this case it is fine and you already received quite a bit of input. See [this thread](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1143/how-long-to-wait-before-reposting-unanswered-mathse-question-to-mo/) on meta.MO. May I suggest that you post and accept a short answer in a few days, indicating that you received a satisfactory answer on MO so that the question here is considered answered here?

Comment: @t.b.: I wasn't sure whether this question was appropriate for MO or not so I asked it here first. If ever I am in this situation again, I will wait a bit longer. Once I accept an answer on MO I will make sure I post something about it here in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/107168/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Liviu Nicolaescu below.

> Here is roughly the  philosophy of  the Weitzenbock technique. (Most of what follows is taken from  Berline-Getzler-Vergne book.)
>
> Suppose that  $E_0,E_1\to M$ are  vector bundles on an oriented Riemann manifolds  $M$ equipped with  hermitian metrics.  Denote by $C^\infty(E_i)$ the space of  smooth sections of $E_i$.
>
> A symmetric 2nd order  differential operator  $L: C^\infty(E_0)\to C^\infty(E_0)$ is called a  *generalized Laplacian*  on $E_0$ if its principal symbol  $\sigma_L$ coincides with the principal symbol of a Laplacian. Concretely this means  the following.
>
> For a smooth function $f\in C^\infty(M)$ denote by $M_f$ the linear operator $C^\infty(E_0)\to C^\infty( E_0)$ defined by the multiplication with $f$. Then $L$ is a generalized Laplacian if for any $f_0,f_1\in C^\infty(M)$  and any  $u\in C^\infty(E_0)$ we have
>
> $$ [\; [\; L,M_{f_0}\; ], M_{f_1}\; ]u = -2g( df_0,df_1)\cdot u $$
>
> where $[-,-]$ denotes the commutator  of two operators.   Equivalently, this means
>
> $$[[L,M_{f_0}],M_{f_1}]=-2M_{g(df_0,df_1)}. $$
>
> One can show that if $L$ is a generalized Laplacian on $E_0$, then there exists a connection   $\nabla$ on $E_0$, compatible with the metric on $E_0$, and a symmetric  endomorphism $W$ of $E_0$ such that
>
> $$ L =\nabla^*\nabla +W. $$
>
> The classical Weitzenbock formulas give explicit descriptions to the Weitzenbock remainder  $W$ and the connection $\nabla$.
>
> Usually  the  generalized Laplacians are  obtained through  *Dirac type* operators which  are first order differential operators $D: C^\infty(E_0)\to C^\infty(E_1)$ such that both operators $D^\ast D$ and  $D D^\ast$ are generalized Laplacians on $E_0$ and respectively $E_1$.  We can rewrite this in a compact form by using the operator
>
> $$\mathscr{D}: C^\infty(E_0)\oplus C^\infty(E_1)\to C^\infty(E_0)\oplus C^\infty(E_1), $$
>
> $$\mathscr{D}(u_0\oplus u_1)= (D^*u_1)\oplus (D u_0). $$
>
> Then $D$ is Dirac type  iff $\mathscr{D}^2$ is a generalized Laplacian.
>
> The Weitzenbock remainders of $D^\ast D$ and $D D^\ast$ involve curvature terms. If the Weitzenbock remainder of $D^*D$ happens to be a positive endomorphism of $E_0$, then one can conclude that
>
> $$\ker D=\ker D^\ast D=0. $$
>
> The  Hodge-Dolbeault operator
>
> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\bar{\partial}+\bar{\partial}^*): \Omega^{0,even}(M)\to \Omega^{0,odd}(M) $$
>
> on a Kahler manifold $M$ is a Dirac type operator. For more details and examples  you can check Sec. 10.1 and Chap 11 of [my lecture notes](http://www.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Lectures.pdf).